# PHP write to file minus the PHP code?

Tags: php, text, strpos

I want to write a file to a file and the file contains some PHP code. I don't want the file to run the PHP when someone reads the file. Basically, I want all the text between the `<?php` and the `?>`, plus those tags. Is there any way to do this in PHP? Possibly with `strpos`? I tried to use strpos; but I couldn't figure it out.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
echo "This is the PHP I want removed!";
?>
<html>
<p>This is what I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

Comment: *"...minus the PHP code"*, *"all the text between `<?php ?>` plus those tags"*? So... you just want the raw PHP file as-is, or what?

Comment: I can't tell quite what your asking.  Can you provide a brief sample input file and desired output?  That would probably clear everything up.

Comment: I want the PHP code remove, and only the HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to parse the file using [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), loop through the result and discard everything that's not of type `T_INLINE_HTML`.

Comment: Never ran into that function before. +1

Comment: @snark Look at the documentation for `token_get_all` for an example of what it gives you. Use `var_dump` to see for yourself. Loop through the array and check if the type of an item is `T_INLINE_HTML` or not. If it is, write it to another file.

Comment: @snark Sorry, try a little harder. Working with arrays is pretty basic stuff you need to get used to ASAP. :)

Comment: Okay I get it. I will use the parser and not be a noob.

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose the filename you're writing to, you can write to a .phps file, which won't be evaluated as PHP. If a visitor views the .phps page, they'll be served up a plaintext file that includes everything inside the `<?php ?>` tags, as well as the HTML.

Comment: That is interesting...thinking outside the box. I'll try it. (With my own extension) :D

Comment: You may need to add `AddType text/plain phps` (or whatever extension you use) to your .htaccess file if you find browsers trying to download the code rather than display it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `<?php ?>` tags are always gonna me at the top of your input file, you could just explode the input and write to your output everything around your tags:

Input:

```
<?php echo "This is the PHP I want removed!"; ?>
<html> 
    <p>This is what I want written to a file!</p> 
</html>
```

Code:

```
$inputTxt = file_get_contents($path . $file , NULL, NULL);

$begin = explode("<?php", $inputTxt);
$end = explode('?>', $inputTxt);
fwrite($output,  $begin[0] . $end[1] . "\n\n");
?>
```

Output:

**Before**

```
<?php
echo "This is the PHP I want removed!";
?>
<html>
<p>This is what I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

**After**

```
<html>
<p>This is what I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

But, if you plan on having more than one set of `<?php ?>` tags, then you would need to use preg_match:

Input:

```
<?php
echo "This is the PHP I want removed!";
?>
<html>
    <p>This is <?php echo $something; ?> I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

Code:

```
<?php
$file="input.txt";
$path='C:\\input\\';
$output = fopen($path . "output.txt",'w');

$inputTxt = file_get_contents($path . $file , NULL, NULL);

$pattern = '/<\?php.+\?>/isU';
$replace = '';

$newInput = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $inputTxt);

fwrite($output,  $newInput);
?>
```

Output:

**Before**

```
<?php
echo "This is the PHP I want removed!";
?>
<html>
<p>This is <?php echo $something; ?> I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

**After**

```
<html>
<p>This is  I want written to a file!</p>
</html>
```

Comment: `<?php echo 'Parse this! ?>'; ?>` :-P

Comment: Touche...  I was trying to give a simplified example.  But I imagine if you were worried about nested php tags you could do a match, then check within that match for nested tags or hanging tags.

Comment: Or you could, you know, use a real parser... ;p